# Why does this EF upsert logic result in deletions instead of updates?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The following code results in deletions instead of updates.

My question is: is this a bug in the way I'm coding against Entity Framework or should I suspect something else?

**Update**: I got this working, but I'm leaving the question now with both the original and the working versions in hopes that I can learn something I didn't understand about EF.

In this, the original **non working** code, when the database is fresh, all the additions of SearchDailySummary object succeed, but on the second time through, when my code was supposedly going to perform the update, **the net result is a once again empty table in the database**, i.e. this logic manages to be the equiv. of removing each entity.

```
    //Logger.Info("Upserting SearchDailySummaries..");
    using (var db = new ClientPortalContext())
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var campaignName = item["campaign"];

            var pk1 = db.SearchCampaigns.Single(c => c.SearchCampaignName == campaignName).SearchCampaignId;
            var pk2 = DateTime.Parse(item["day"].Replace('-', '/'));

            var source = new SearchDailySummary
            {
                SearchCampaignId = pk1,
                Date = pk2,
                Revenue = decimal.Parse(item["totalConvValue"]),
                Cost = decimal.Parse(item["cost"]),
                Orders = int.Parse(item["conv1PerClick"]),
                Clicks = int.Parse(item["clicks"]),
                Impressions = int.Parse(item["impressions"]),
                CurrencyId = item["currency"] == "USD" ? 1 : -1 // NOTE: non USD (if exists) -1 for now
            };

            var target = db.Set<SearchDailySummary>().Find(pk1, pk2) ?? new SearchDailySummary();
            if (db.Entry(target).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                db.SearchDailySummaries.Add(target);
                addedCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                // TODO?: compare source and target and change the entity state to unchanged if no diff
                updatedCount++;
            }

            AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(source, target);

            itemCount++;
        }

        Logger.Info("Saving {0} SearchDailySummaries ({1} updates, {2} additions)", itemCount, updatedCount, addedCount);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Here is the **working version** (although I'm not 100% it's optimized, it's working reliably and performing fine as long as I batch it out in groups of 500 or less items in a shot - after that it slows down exponentially but I think that just may be a different question/subject)...

```
    //Logger.Info("Upserting SearchDailySummaries..");
    using (var db = new ClientPortalContext())
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var campaignName = item["campaign"];

            var pk1 = db.SearchCampaigns.Single(c => c.SearchCampaignName == campaignName).SearchCampaignId;
            var pk2 = DateTime.Parse(item["day"].Replace('-', '/'));

            var source = new SearchDailySummary
            {
                SearchCampaignId = pk1,
                Date = pk2,
                Revenue = decimal.Parse(item["totalConvValue"]),
                Cost = decimal.Parse(item["cost"]),
                Orders = int.Parse(item["conv1PerClick"]),
                Clicks = int.Parse(item["clicks"]),
                Impressions = int.Parse(item["impressions"]),
                CurrencyId = item["currency"] == "USD" ? 1 : -1 // NOTE: non USD (if exists) -1 for now
            };

            var target = db.Set<SearchDailySummary>().Find(pk1, pk2);
            if (target == null)
            {
                db.SearchDailySummaries.Add(source);
                addedCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(source, target);
                db.Entry(target).State = EntityState.Modified;
                updatedCount++;
            }

            itemCount++;
        }

        Logger.Info("Saving {0} SearchDailySummaries ({1} updates, {2} additions)", itemCount, updatedCount, addedCount);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The thing that keeps popping up in my mind is that maybe the `Entry(entity)` or `Find(pk)` method has some side effects?  I should probably be consulting the documentation but any advice is appreciated..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a slight assumption on my part (without looking into your models/entities), but have a look at what's going on within this block (see if the objects being attached here are related to the deletions):

```
if (db.Entry(target).State == EntityState.Detached)
{
    db.SearchDailySummaries.Add(target);
    addedCount++;
}
```

Your detached object won't be able to use its navigation properties to locate its related objects; you'll be re-attaching an object in a potentially conflicting state (without the correct relationships).

You haven't mentioned what is being deleted above, so I may be way off. Just off out, so this is a little rushed, hope there's something useful in there.

Comment: Thanks for the input.. i'm still a bit confused but I updated my question based on your response..

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I'm on the right track actually, I'll try and mock up a local version if I get a chance, so it's clearer in my head as well =D

Comment: It might be worth putting a breakpoint at the `Automapper.Mapper.Map()` line, and inspecting the target and source in both versions.